# Как правильно использовать widget чтобы он не тормозил загрузку веб сайта?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, браузер

После  вставки кода Yandex weather (widget) , увеличилось время загрузки веб сайта.

Как нужно правильно  использовать внешние коды (виджеты), чтобы время загрузки страницы несильно менялось ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1) 
Выводить виджет после загрузки DOM

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    document.querySelector('.selector_parent_your_widget').innerHtml = 'your_widget_code';
});
```

Вариант 2)

Вы можете воспользоваться API яндекс погоды. Оно подключается по запросу и имеет бесплатный тариф на 50 запросов в сутки при соблюдении условий размещения. С актуальными условиями размещения можете ознакомиться [здесь](https://tech.yandex.ru/weather/doc/dg/concepts/pricing-docpage/#about__branding).
А чтобы не превысить лимит 50 запросов в сутки используйте кэширование.

Comment: А можно ли дисплей  контейнера в котором   должен будет находится widget сделать  none  а после загрузки страницы сделать видимым (display:block) ,  повисит ли это время загрузки страницы ?

Comment: @a_mine нет, в данном случае элемент на странице будет просто невидим и на скорость загрузки страницы это никак не повлияет